# adf projet from weblogic to tomcat

Tags: tomcat, weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have an adf projet developed with jdeveloper and running fine on weblogic server but i can't make it run on tomcat

i tried many things like copying jar libraries to tomcat directories, deploying with tomcat manager and copying the war file directly, changing deployment profile settings in jdeveloper, trying other versions of jdk, trying with a simple hello world application.
either the application is deployed and won't start, or it won't deploy at all, or tomcat won't start.
i managed one time to start the application but the pages are blank.

> 31 juil. 2019 13:09:36 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path
>   [/tomcatProfil] threw exception [L'uri absolue:
>   http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich ne peut être résolu dans le
>   fichier web.xml ou dans les fichiers jar déployés avec cette
>   application] with root cause org.apache.jasper.JasperException: L'uri
>   absolue: http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich ne peut être résolu
>   dans le fichier web.xml ou dans les fichiers jar déployés avec cette
>   application   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:325)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:419)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:484)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1421)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:660)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2575)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2564)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 31 juil. 2019 13:09:36
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke GRAVE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path
>   [/tomcatProfil] threw exception [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.jsp.tomcatProfil_jsp] with root cause
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.tomcatProfil_jsp     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:409)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2575)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2564)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: What error message do you get ?

Comment: i added a picture to the question

Comment: This is like 20 lines of an error stack trace that must have 200 lines. (And in french) Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rework your question. At a first look you're missing the required ADF libraries on your tomcat.

Comment: It look like you are missing all the required adf libraries. Did you do the following : https://flexagon.com/2017/02/how-to-adf-essentials-12c-application-on-tomcat-8/ and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b25947/deployment_topics012.htm ?

Comment: nope, i will now